# Как узнать полный путь добавленного файла Access в проекте?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, access, oledb

Файл access был добавлен в проект как "существующий элемент", после в свойстве "действие при сборке" выбран  "внедренный ресурс".
С файлом access буду работать по принципу oledb c#.

```
var path = "MyProject.Data.DB.accdb";
```

Comment: А случаем внедрённый ресурс не внедряется в сборку, т.е. в dll?

Comment: возможно, но должна узнать путь прежде чем работать с файлом

Answer (score 1):

Никак.

Прежде чем работать с файлом через `OleDb` тебе его нужно материализовать в обычный файл.

Если посмотреть [этот](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/) сайт, то тут нету синтаксиса работы с внедренным файлом, а только через файловую систему. Оно и понятно, так как каждый язык может внедрять ресурсы по своему, а `OleDb` не привязан к конкретному языку.

Во [тут](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/40e97e/saving-an-embedded-file-in-C-Sharp/) приводится пример доставания Exe из ресурса:

```
Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("EmbedExe.regedt32.exe");
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("new.exe", FileMode.CreateNew);
            for (int i = 0; i < stream.Length; i++)
                fileStream.WriteByte((byte)stream.ReadByte());
            fileStream.Close();
```

Comment: материализовать в обычный файл? что под этим имеете виду?

Comment: Ну как я понял вы храните файл, как ресурс внутри сборки. Прежде чем с ним работать, нужно его достать из сборки и сохранить в файловой системе.

Comment: если не добавлять как ресурс . А искать файл в папке с проектом

Comment: Ну в этом случае есть спец. метод, с помощью которого можно найти директорию, где хранится exe-файл запускаемый.

Comment: как осуществить поиск файла в проекте с файлами. Так как путь программы может меняться. В зависимости от пользователя.

Comment: поэтому файл добавила в проект. Можно ли узнать полный путь файла

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-assembly-the-code-is-in